# Google Sites HTTPS issue

Tags: https, google-sites

I'm wondering if anyone can help with this.

I'm creating a site for a client using Google Sites (A requirement they set).

One of their requirement is for a contact form to be embedded on the site. I've had a look and there are plenty out there, however, if a user visits from any version of IE the content is not displayed due to the security settings.

All other browsers are functioning fine.
I know the alternative is to simply put a link to an external source, but is not ideal.

My question is threefold fold.
1. Is it possible to write a gadget that will work for IE with non-secure content (if so how)?
2. Are there any HTTPS contact forms out there that I could use?
3. Does anyone have any experience with Google sites and trying to load non-secure content and have any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried JotForm.com? They have the same (free and premium) plans as emailmeform.com. Plus, they have a specific roundabouts to embed your form in Google Sites (they have a gadget made for Google Sites). And yes, JotForm has https url for their forms if you wish to embed it as an iframe.

-- One other solution is resort to using Google Docs form.

> Does anyone have any experience with Google sites and trying to load
>   non-secure content and have any tips? Still awaiting people with
>   experience....

-- Yes, I have experienced this while trying to put some social media scripts in my Google Sites website and the best thing really was to rid my Sites of those non-secure contents.

Answer (score 0):

For any interested I have kind of answered my questions.

1. Is it possible to write a gadget that will work for IE with non-secure content (if so how)? 
   It is possible but you need to have a SSL hosted server.
2. Are there any HTTPS contact forms out there that I could use? 
   There are paid solutions for this. Alternatively, write your own html code to post to one of these solutions (free solution is http://www.emailmeform.com/)
3. Does anyone have any experience with Google sites and trying to load non-secure content and have any tips?
   Still awaiting people with experience....